# How to make custom module menu selected in drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a custom module in drupal 7 which shows a navigation menu in admin menu bar , but when I click on it it is not selected . Here is the menu hook

```
function tableof_content_menu() {
    $items['admin/tableof_content/add'] = array(
    'title' => t('Add TOC'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('tableof_content_admin_add_form'),
    //'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('administer my module'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );

   $items['admin/tableof_content/edit/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit TOC',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('tableof_content_admin_add_form',3),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  ); 

   $items['admin/tableof_content/search/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Add TOC',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('tableof_content_admin_add_form',3),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
   );

  return $items;
}
```

Also I have checked with firebug and in other menu the class "active-trail" is showing which is not appearing in my menu .

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Did you also create a route for admin/tableof_content (the parent of your menu item "add")?

Comment: I have edited my post @Djouuuuh , please check

Comment: Ok. You created 3 children for the admin/tableof_content "menu". I'm not sure but I think you have to set this route too. Could you have a look at this article: http://www.konordo.com/blog/drupal-7-add-custom-link-admin-menu

Comment: @Djouuuuh thanks for your help  but  I have tried the trick they provide but after cache clear still it is not working as I am required

Comment: Unfortunately I also found this article (https://www.drupal.org/node/942782) that says that custom menu items don't receive "active-trail" class by default...

Comment: @Djouuuuh I checked that previously but they are creating custom menu through admin and I am creating using hook_menu . The issue is that oen of my colleague create a custom module and it selecting the menu and I have done same as he did but its not highlighting for my module :(

Comment: Maybe you could do the trick dynamically. In each page view, you can use menu_set_active_item("admin/tableof_content/add").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59589/discussion-between-ron-and-djouuuuh).

Comment: @Djouuuuh I have checked one thing that when we create a custom module the class that generate is class="active" but for default the class generated is class="active-trail". BTW thanks for your help

Comment: Try chucking https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path in there, that usually solves active trail problems pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do the trick dynamically in each node_view. You get the current node path with `$path = menu_get_active_trail()` and you set the menu item as active with `menu_set_active_item($path)`. I had to do that once.